# Visual Studio project properties missing after changing language

Tags: visual-studio

after changing the language (from german to english) the  project properties are missing. It says "There are no property pages for this selection".

Tried reinstalling (I'm at 3 times now) aswell as repair. Also tried installing te english version directly, instead of switching languages after installation.

Same problem here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d5eba0af-724c-482d-a908-df73c4c2f353/broken-project-property-page-in-vs-c-projects-when-using-english-language?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Some additional information: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community (the error also occured on earlier versions) on Windows 10. The project itself is an old C++ VS2010 project (I'm trying to avoid upgrading it) and the *.vcxproj file doesn't contain any language specific options.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Is the problem specific to that old C++ VS2010 project or to all projects? If you want to try it on a fresh computer, you could install, say, a trial version of Server 2016 in a virtual machine in Hyper-V.

Comment: It seems to be a VS2010 project specific problem. Tried it with a new project, works even after switching languages. As there obviously is a fix for the problem I'm still trying to avoid upgrading the project because it runs on several computers (some of them with VS2010).

Comment: 1) If you change the language back to German does it work again? Would that be a viable workaround when you want to use the property pages? 2) If you make a copy of the project and then upgrade that copy, does it work? If so, would upgrading the computers running VS2010 to VS2017 be an option?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer: So I did update the solution to a newer version, had to update several librarys aswell because the new compiler had some issues with them. I guess I could somehow used the old one but now it's done. Apperently there is no other fix for the problem I guess. Thanks anyways.